# Is there a way to add custom annotation on generated wsdl classes without modify the wsdl source with gradle?

Tags: xml, wsdl, wsdl2java

I have some classes generated from wsdl that I need to use in a software. All things are fine until I try to write a test case that aims to verify the consistence of the response body. The problem here is that the test fails because of different hash codes.

```
There is no type conversion possible from it.agos.soap.npc16.daticlientepercf.GetDatiDocNewResponse to it.agos.soap.npc16.daticlientepercf.GetDatiDocNewResponse$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$f6fda147
```

What I want to do is to modify my build.gradle file task where I execute the generating task in order to add a lombok @Data annotation to the generated classes, without modify my wsdl file (I can't do it).
This is my wsdl2java task:

```
task generateClassesFromWsdl(group: 'build', description: 'Generate classes from WSDL') {
    inputs.files fileTree(dir: 'src/main/resources/wsdl', include:'**/*.wsdl')
    String genSrcDir = "src/generated/java"
    outputs.dir genSrcDir
    inputs.files.each { file -> 
        doLast {
            OutputStream baos;
            javaexec {
                println "Generating classes for $file.name"
                classpath configurations.wsdl2java
                main "org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava"
                args '-encoding', 'UTF-8', '-d', genSrcDir, file
                baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
                errorOutput = new OutputStream() {
                    void write(int b) {System.err.write(b); baos.write(b) }  
                    void flush() { System.err.flush(); baos.flush() }
                    void close() { System.err.close(); baos.close() }
                }
            }
            def str = baos.toString()
            if (str.contains('Usage : wsdl2java') || str.contains('WSDLToJava Error')) {
                throw new TaskExecutionException(tasks[name], 
                new IOException('Apache CXF WSDLToJava has failed. Please see System.err output.'))
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

I have tried to look on other answers, but I don't find anything useful for my case, how can I handle this issue?
Thanks!

Comment: did you find a solution? I also need to do like this

Comment: @AbdulFatah no I'm sorry, I had tested the services in a different way

Comment: No problem. I found solution to my problem. Actually I wanted to be able to annotate classes with lombok annotations for implementing builder pattern. Luckily it was possible by using a jaxb plugin called rich contracts